# What international law requires armed police to be present in international airports?

Tags: international, aviation, firearms

Among its reasons for reintroducing weapons into Solomon Islands' police force, [RAMSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Assistance_Mission_to_Solomon_Islands) [states that](http://www.ramsi.org/works/firearms/)

> Under international conventions it is a requirement that all international airports maintain an armed police presence. Without rearmament, the RSIPF will not be able to meet this obligation, which would impact on their ability to have a working international airport.

Which international conventions are referred to here and what is the rationale for this requirement?  What are the extent of these obligations?

Comment: It might be helpful for you to look at the International Civil Aviation Organizations website.